# Create NSDictionary format as per JSON Request in POST method

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdictionary

I need to POST datas to JSON. I don't know how to convert to NSDictionary for some complicated JSON format.
Format is below:

```
//1.JSON FORMAT
{ 
    "username": "qqq_qq@qqq.qq",
    "password": "******" 
}

//In Swift:

var params = ["username": nameTxtFld.text, "password" : passTxtFld.text] as Dictionary<String, String> 
//WORKING

//2. JSON FROMAT
{
    "name":"qqq",
    "emailId":"qqq_qq@qqq.qq",
    "user":{
        "password":"****",
        "confirmPassword":"****"
    }
}

//In Swift

var parameters = ["userName": nameTxtFld.text, "email": emailTxtFld.text, "user" : ["password" : passTxtFld.text, "confirmPassword" : confPassTxtFld.text]] as Dictionary<String, String, String> 
//Error
//Unprintable ASCII character found in source file
```

Kindly guide me? How to covert this format in NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send a JSON format request to web server, why don't you create a String with the formatted keys and values like @"username=xxxx&password=xxx" and then while adding this string to NSMUtableURLRequest class, convert this string to NSData and then add it.
This will be format we can use while sending POST type of request.

Comment: How to convert like that? I am very new to JSON.

Comment: First prepare a string like NSString * str = @"username=xxxx&password=xxx"; Now create a NSData object from the above string like NSData * data = [str singEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];. Set this data object to NSMUtableURLRequest class's set httpbody method.

Comment: "user":{
        "password":"****",
        "confirmPassword":"****"
    }   Then, this nested data???

Comment: Ok, lets do this, NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndValues:];NSData *dataFromDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                         error:&error];
Now add this data to NSMUtableURLRequest class. This should work.

Comment: var parameters = ["userName": nameTxtFld.text, "email": emailTxtFld.text, "user" : ["password" : passTxtFld.text, "confirmPassword" : confPassTxtFld.text]]

Comment: That only I did. But, error I received. I don't know how to write nested NSDictionary as JSON request. If you know, kindly reply me.